# Getting An exception While following a tutorial

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BazFP71ju28&list=PLXy8DQl3058OoJqGLFdqoBkBKm2T0kS9B&index=2&ab_channel=LiliumCode & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xloj8KtI8k&list=PLXy8DQl3058OoJqGLFdqoBkBKm2T0kS9B&index=3

In the first video, he creates a person index using annotations instead of creating a json file with the mappings which he does (to create vehicle index) in this part. After that he implements search feature on the vehicle index and says it can be similarly be implemented for the person index. I tried it out but am getting an exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "_class" (class com.elastic.elasticsearch.document.Person), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "id", "name"])
 at [Source: (String)"{"_class":"com.elastic.elasticsearch.document.Person","id":"1","name":"Jason"}"; line: 1, column: 12] (through reference chain: com.elastic.elasticsearch.document.Person["_class"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:61) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:1127) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1989) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1700) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1678) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:319) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:176) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:322) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4674) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3629) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3597) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]
    at com.elastic.elasticsearch.service.PersonService.search(PersonService.java:67) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.elastic.elasticsearch.controller.PersonController.search(PersonController.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:359) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1735) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

I am attaching the changes/functions I created to make the search:
PersonService.java:

```
@Service
public class PersonService {
private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonService.class);

private final RestHighLevelClient client;

private final PersonRepository repository;

@Autowired
public PersonService(PersonRepository repository, RestHighLevelClient client) {
    this.repository = repository;
    this.client = client;
}
```

//save function
//findById function

```
public List<Person> search(final SearchRequestDTO dto) {
    final SearchRequest request = SearchUtil.buildSearchRequest(Indices.PERSON_INDEX, dto);
    
    if (request == null) {
        LOG.error("Failed to build search request");
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    try {
        final SearchResponse response = client.search(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

        final SearchHit[] searchHits = response.getHits().getHits();
        final List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>(searchHits.length);
        for (SearchHit hit : searchHits) {
            persons.add(
                    MAPPER.readValue(hit.getSourceAsString(), Person.class)
            );
        }

        return persons;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

}

Endpoint for search in PersonController.java:

```
@PostMapping("/search")
    public List<Person> search(@RequestBody final SearchRequestDTO dto) {
        return service.search(dto);
    }
```

[Search request through postman:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cswth.png)

[Proof that 'Jason' exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V4L9.png)

The rest of the files (SearchDTO, SearchUtil etc are same as in the videos mentioned above) and the full project can be found at: https://github.com/SiDMerceR1/ES_Test/tree/main/elasticsearch

Versions:
Spring Boot: 2.6.4
Spring Data ES: 4.3.2
ES: 7.17.1

Please help me figure out how to deal with this exception. Thank you.

Comment: This code does not use Spring Data Elasticsearch. It uses the Elasticsearch client and manually parses the response with an ObjectMapper into a Person object. Please read the documentation at at https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#reference how to use Spring Data Elasticsearch

Comment: You cannot ask person to go through the video and solve your problem. Its better you explain the issue by yourself or replicate the issue and provide the public access to your repository.

Comment: @AnishPanthi Good suggestion, I uploaded the repository link.

Answer (score 0):

So I looked at the documentation as suggested by @P.J.Meisch and found this solution:

Defined this method in PersonRepository:

```
List<Person> findByName(String name);
```

Defined this in the PersonService:

```
public List<Person> search(final SearchRequestDTO dto) {
        return repository.findByName(dto.getSearchTerm());
    }
```

And now I am getting the result:

[image: screenshot]

Please let me know if this is the correct way to do this.